# Choosing whether to add or not a templating library to an existent Codeigniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, template-engine

So I have reached a certain point in the development of my app where having this folder structure:

```
views/
     includes/{header.php, template.php, footer.php}
     home.php
     xyz.php
     ...
```

and loading the views this way

### controller.php

```
    $data['lists'] = $lists;
    $data['view'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

### template.php

```
<?php
    $this->lang->load('common');
    if($view == 'videoPage') 
    {
        $header['title']       = $data['title'].' - XYZ.com ';
        $header['description'] = $data['description'];
        $header['keywords']    = implode(', ',$data['tags']);
        $header['canonical']   = $data['canonical'];
        $this->load->view('includes/header', $header);
    }
    elseif (($view == "searchsPage") || ($view == 'tagsPage'))
    {
        $header['title'] = $query.' - XYZ.com ';
        $this->load->view('includes/header', $header);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
    }
?>
    <div role="container">
        <?php
            if ( ! empty($data))
            {
                $this->load->view($view, $data);
                if(($view == 'searchsPage') OR ($view == 'tagsPage')):
                ?>

                ...SPECIFIC CODE HERE...

                <?php endif;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view($view);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

and more...

Is starting to get a little bit messy, so I was wondering if is worth it to implement an existing templating library from http://getsparks.org/search (search for "template") or just do some improving to the one I use? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also started implementing library on my own but after a while it got messy and then changed to existing one. Specifically I used Phil Sturgeon's Library and it's a good one. The link to the library http://getsparks.org/packages/template/versions/HEAD/show.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own template library and keep your code DRY. You dont need to inlcude footer and header everytime.  Also you can look at already written template modelings.

Here list of some [Codeigniter template libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957000/what-codeigniter-template-library-is-best)